# HTTPS QOS and policing

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios, qos, policing

In our office, everything runs on HTTPS. We have softphones and web-based clients which are high priority. We also have Google search, maps and other low priority websites that should work on best-effort basis.

But there is no way to differentiate between this traffic. We can't do it based on IP because most of the hosts have dynamic IPs.

How do you deal with this?

Comment: You can differentiate by destination address.  IP phones talk to a PBX; other traffic goes to the Internet.  Or you can use ports.  You can filter on that.

Comment: I have got IP phones covered but the web-based clients don't have static IPs.

Comment: You use ACLs to differentiate the traffic. You do not need to know the source IP addresses, so it doesn't matter that the sources do not have static addresses. You want to mark as close to the source as possible, probably on the access switches, so that you can treat the traffic during its entire life inside your network..

Comment: There's no way to differentiate as I said. Traffic goes to dynamic IPs and all of them have the same port.

Comment: You could segment out the high priority clients into their own VLAN. Then you could apply the proper QoS policy to entire IP range and still use dynamic addressing. However, is it really needed? QoS does nothing unless there is congestion. If you have a bandwidth problem, I'd solve that before I'd attempt to micro manage traffic like that.